# Sign function and complex number proof

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\lambda$ is the sign function, how can I prove that

$\sqrt{\lambda}\left ( 1-i \right )=1-\lambda i$

when $\lambda\neq0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\lambda$ can only assume the values $-1,0,1$. Consider these cases separately.

You have already excluded the case ) $\lambda=0$.

When $\lambda=1$, the statement becomes $1-i =1-i$, which is clearly true.

What happens when $\lambda=-1$?

**Edit:** Since you have the solution, I'll verify it. Note that

$$\sqrt{\pm 1} = \frac{1+ i}2 \pm \frac{1-i}2$$
so that
$$\sqrt{\pm 1}\cdot(1-i) = \frac{(1+ i)(1-i)}2 \pm \frac{(1- i)(1-i)}2$$
$$=\frac{1^2-i^2}2 \pm\frac{1-2i+i^2}2$$
$$=\frac{1+1}2 \pm \frac{1-2i-1}2$$
$$=\frac22 \pm \frac{-2i}2$$
$$=1 \mp i$$
$$= 1 - (\pm1)i$$

Comment: What about $\sqrt{\lambda}(1+i)=1+i\lambda$? I've tried following your derivation but couldn't confirm this.

Comment: You can do it. Just start with $\sqrt{\pm1}\cdot(1+i)$ instead, and follow similar simplification steps.

Comment: I arrive to $i\pm1$. Isn't this $\pm1\left(  \frac{i}{\pm1} +1\right)=\lambda\left(  1+i\lambda\right)$?

Comment: Well, the statement $\sqrt{\lambda}(1+i) = 1+i\lambda$" is false. Consider the two cases separately. When $\lambda=1$, the statement is "$1(1+i)=1+i(1)$", which is true; but when $\lambda=-1$, the statement is "$i(1+i) = 1+i(-1)$", i.e., "$-1+i = 1-i$", which is false.

Comment: Indeed, that was what I suspected. I am studying an Oceanography paper and I believe there is a mistake in it. The authors say that eliminating $K_V$ from $c=\sqrt{\frac{i f}{K_{V}}}$ with $D=\pi \sqrt{\frac{2 K_{V}}{|f|}}$ results in $c=(1+i \lambda) \frac{\pi}{D}$, where $\lambda=\frac{f}{|f|}$.

Comment: That’s different. This is a complex setting, so we aren’t talking about a sign function, instead we have $f/|f|=e^{i\theta}$. We also have to consider which branch cut is used for the root. Let me think about this. Do you have more info about $K_V$? Is it real?

Comment: $K_V$ is a real number, it is the coefficient of turbulent viscosity in the vertical direction. The parameter $c$ arises from the solution of a second-order differential equation. I can send you my full derivation of the equation, should you have the patience to go through it.

Comment: The error was mine. The paper is correct. I only accounted for the principal root in this: $\sqrt{\frac{i f}{K_{V}}}=\sqrt{i} \frac{\sqrt{f}}{\sqrt{K_{V}}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \frac{\sqrt{f}}{\frac{\sqrt{|f| D}}{\pi \sqrt{2}}}(1+i)=\sqrt{\lambda}(1+i) \frac{\pi}{D}$.

Accounting for both roots gives $(\pm1)(1+i)\sqrt{\lambda}$ which is the same as $\underbrace{(\pm1)}_{=\lambda}\underbrace{(1+i)\sqrt{\lambda}}_{=\lambda(1+i\lambda)}=\lambda^{2}(1+i\lambda)=(1+i\lambda)$.